# How to use Exoplayer in android code to start my rasperbypi camera?

Tags: media-player, exoplayer

I was searching for the information about using exoplayer since three days. I downloaded the demo app and I understood how it work.

Question is about application development. I want to make an android app, which interact with my raspberry, is integrated with cam.

Actually I have web server which is REST implementation. I can start, stop and record the live video in my sd card from my host machine. Now I want to make an android app. In which one of my friend suggested to go with Exoplayer but that isn't UDP or RTP support. It supports DASH, HLS.

Now I m wondering what protocol do I need to implement to send my video packets to  Exoplayer.

Don't know which protocol I need to use to transfer live video packets to Exoplayer ?

Feedback more appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

What is format of camera output? MPEG-2 TS?

A couple options

**1) HLS**

I find HLS easier to deal with and it's been around longer so there is a lot info to be found online.

Here are [Apple's guidelines for creating a HLS stream](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2224/_index.html).

The HLS solution make the server-side complicated because you have to package the TS into HLS segments and generate the m3u8 playlist. But it makes the client easy because, as you noted, ExoPlayer supports HLS out of the box.

**2) UDP**

If you want to make the server-side easy you can just open a UDP port and start sending TS out as UDP datagrams. However this makes the client side complicated because you will have to write a Loader that reads UDP and then use ExoPlayer's [TsExtractor](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/extractor/ts/TsExtractor.java). And you'll have to deal with out-of-order and lost datagrams.